# Combining the detection of smoke+motion+temperature+light in a single wired device

Tags: sensors, wired, plc

I'm working on a prototype home automation for our to-be renovated off-grid farmhouse. Much of the house will run directly on 24V DC (except the power devices like microwave etc).The whole setup will be fairly along the lines of [Femme's setup](https://gathering.tweakers.net/forum/list_messages/1632953) (a Dutch entrepeneur and serious tweaker).

- Raspberry PI + node-red
- [Railduino](https://sedtronic.eu/en/railduino/4-22-railduino-21.html#/3-relays_type-12x_classic_relays_7a), [WAGO PLC](https://www.wago.com/global/automation-technology/discover-plcs/pfc200)
- temperature, humidity, light measurement with 1-wire
- presence detection with PIR and radar to digital inputs
- fire and heat detection with 24V fire detectors to digital inputs, SlowWhoop on digital output
- impulse switches on walls to digital inputs
- control of valves on central heating manifolds by digital outputs
- LED lighting (probably with DMX)
- ...all wired

I'm trying to work my sensors away in already existing elements in the house where I'll be pulling UTP cables to anyway and will run 24V through. Those elements are wall switches at hip height and the smoke detectors on the ceiling. By placing the sensors there, I save myself additional cable management and even more cable pulling. The sensors can be connected to the remaining cores in the UTP cable.

The temperature, humidity and light sensor by [Taaralabs](https://taaralabs.eu/1-wire-temperature-humidity-light-sensor/) or [Sedtronic](https://sedtronic.eu/en/unica-1wire/30-52-unica-1-wire-tvsl.html#/1-pcb_protection-no_coating) can easily be concealed behind a blind plate next to the impulse switch in a duo flush-mounting box together with [this PIR](https://shop.bb-sensors.com/en/Motion-Brightness/PIR-motion-sensor-power-consumption-1-0-mA.html) by B+B (or the ds18b20) and this [radar sensor](https://www.amazon.nl/gp/product/B081J44XCK/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1).

The temperature sensors will hang fine at that (hip) height; better than at the smoke detector on the ceiling because it's warmer there. But the motion and light sensors would be better positioned near the ceiling, because of the improved "visibility" and thus more effective functioning.

Therefore I am looking for a multifunctional ceiling sensor set that works on low voltage (ideally 24V) and measures both smoke (with heat), and movement, and light. And possibly also CO and humidity. Smoke and motion would be easy to combine because they work binary (open or closed). The light sensor would then additionally require either 1-wire or analog output and makes the combination with smoke reporting a little less obvious. But still functionally a logical combination of sensors there on the ceiling.

What do you guys think of this strategy and who knows of examples of these multi-functional low voltage sensors?

*BTW: I've found low voltage smoke detectors, like the [SensoMAG S30](https://teletek-electronics.com/en/products/fire-alarm-solution/conventional/conventional-detectors/sensomag-s30-110/) by Teletek electronics, and the [Notifier ECO1002](https://www.notifier.nl/product.asp?id=388) by Honeywell. Also I found multifunctional sensors,  but they are wireless: [Aeotec MultiSensor 6](https://aeotec.com/z-wave-sensor/index.html) or the [Yale fire and PIR motion detector](https://yalehome.co.uk/smoke-detector-intruder-sync-alarm-range/).*

*Update. I just found [OWL wired](https://getowlhome.com/) which is perfect in terms of the sensor package. Unfortunately it comes with their own proprietary app, which I suspect means I can't raw read the sensor output with node-red directly. I don't like to be dependant on somebody else's closed source software (in the cloud) to be able read out the sensors.*

Comment: seems like a good plan ... look into POE (power over ethernet)

Comment: I like PoE, but that isn't solving my main problem, which is combining the detection of smoke+motion+temperature+light in a single device that is wired (with UTP) to my PLC/1-wire controller/Raspberry PI etc.

Comment: your "main problem" is lost in the extensive description, mainly because the only question is `What do you guys think?`

Comment: You're right, I'll try to rewrite it and make my main problem more clear. I didn't expected this to be seen as a shopping question though...

Comment: `Therefore I am looking for a multifunctional ceiling sensor set that works on low voltage` reads as a description of a shopping list

Comment: I think a shopping list question is a spectrum. And some questions within it may still be a good fit. I can't even find a single product on the internet that fits my requirements. I'll leave this question as it stands for anyone who may have experience with such a device or may have even built one themselves...

Comment: "wall switches at hip height" unless that's common in your country, changing the height of switches is hazardous in the dark should automation fail and/or when emergency crews need to come it.